# Checking if an Excel cell contains EXACT text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am aware of the `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(substring,text))` trick to check if an Excel cell contains specific text, as well as the `=ISNUMBER(FIND(substring,text))` [version](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/10/07/excel-find-search-functions/) to so the same thing, but in a case sensitive manner.

I want to do something similar.  I want to return TRUE if an Excel cell contains the **exact** text i.e. if the pattern of interest is a subset of the cell's content the formula returns FALSE.

Comment: can you provide couple of examples? FIND method will search for the exact string within another string, so it is not clear what is your definition of exact.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick  Assume my A1 cell is `Subsetting Pack`.  The formula `=ISNUMBER(FIND("Pack",A1))` evaluates to TRUE. However, I want the formula to evaluate to TRUE only if A1 cell has the exact pattern `Pack` (and not `Subsetting Pack`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to match the whole string in the cell to the search string, why not  simply use

```
=A1="Pack"
```

instead of Search/Find functions?

Answer (score 2):

*"check if an Excel cell contains specific text...but in a case sensitive manner"*

The answer is in both the title and the body of your question; you can use the `EXACT()` function:

```
=EXACT(A1,"Pack")
```